# Run a loop "once" for the entire sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code and it works "kinda", it loops until I press ESC to break the code.

I'm trying to make it run once for the entire sheet, my problem is this as to work in a several sheets that can have one or more words "Especificação"!

Can anyone help!!

```
Sub p_esp_fab()
Dim C As Range
For Each C In Range("A1: II5000")

    Cells.Find(What:="Especificação", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    Selection.Merge True
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "de fabricante"


Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Why are you looping over such a huge range? Do you really have that much data? The code seems terribly inefficient, and its purpose is not at all clear. The question is also vague. You want to do something else in other sheets, but you haven't said what that something else is, only it involves multiple "Especificação".

Comment: My understanding of what you want is that you want to find all occurrences of "Especificação" in a given range, and then copy some data (based on where the "Especificação" was found) to another worksheet. Then you want to perform this search and copy on other worksheets? Is this correct?

Comment: I know very little programming, I used the record macro of excel to create this! the objective is to find and copy the format of the merged cells were the word "Especificação" to the row below and add the words "de fabricante". this is to be used in several excel files and the files can have one to a few dozens of changes to be made.